# can I use AC top cover for Trane XR16

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

My contractor installed this system yesterday, at my property:

"Trane T4TTR6060C1000A RX16 5 TON XR16 A/C 16 SEER rating R410A".

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7uO-n40pIiESGJBdmhlUnFkbDQ&usp=sharing

- I noticed that unit is installed under my gutters. My contractor said that it is not a problem, but the unit has an open top, and I afraid that debris, leaves and other obstacles can get inside the unit.

Question: Can I buy any top cover? So, the leaves and other debris do not get inside the unit? Something like the following:

[http://www.amazon.com/Heavy-Duty-Outdoor-Conditioner-Cover/dp/B003CUWQCA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003CUWQCA)

Answer (score 1):

These units are designed to be outside, so there's no reason to cover it. If you're really concerned about it, go ahead and cover it. Just make sure you don't restrict the airflow, as that can impact how well the unit works.

The manufacture likely recommends annual cleaning, and maintenance. Which will probably do more good for the unit than the cover.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can buy covers, and check this one out, too... perfect for urban duck hunting

[image]

Comment: lol ... is it artificial or real pine tree branches ?

Comment: That looks like an easy service call to me.  "*Take that junk off the unit, it's restricting the air flow.  That'll be $150.00, have a nice day*".

Comment: @Tester101 yes, but the question was, can you buy it? VLR, I'm sure it's fake, and probably sheds worse than a real tree.